# Type erasure of command object using generics in Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, generics, spring-mvc

In a Spring 3.1 MVC app with Hibernate 4.1, the scenario is:

- a webpage displays a list of records where the user is able to select records with a checkbox
- on POST, the selected records will be deleted

Since this functionality also appears in other places, i would like to use generics in order to avoid replicating the similar code.

The logic is:

- on GET, i populate a list using generics which holds the hibernate object and a boolean and i am adding that list to the model
- on POST, i obtain that list from the model and i am passing it to a service in order to delete the selected records

The code is:

```
/* list item */
public class SelectionListItem<T> {

    /* holds the hibernate object */
    private T item;
    /* whether the record is selected */
    private boolean selected;

    public SelectionListItem() {

    }

    public SelectionListItem(T item, boolean selected) {
        this.item = item;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}

/* list that holds the records */
public class SelectionList<T> {

    private List<SelectionListItem<T>> list = new ArrayList<SelectionListItem<T>>();

    public SelectionList() {

    }

    public List<SelectionListItem<T>> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<SelectionListItem<T>> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}


/* Controller for GET */
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String functionGET(Model model) {
    // Retrieve data from database and prepare the list
    SelectionList<MyDomainObject> selectionList = someService.getRecordsAndPrepareList();

    // Add command object to model
    model.addAttribute("selectionListCommand", selectionList);


    return "xxx";
}

/* Service that retrieves the records and prepares the list */
public SelectionList<MyDomainObject> getRecordsAndPrepareList() {
    List<MyDomainObject> result = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MyDomainObject.class).list();

    SelectionList<MyDomainObject> selectionList = new SelectionList<MyDomainObject>();
    for (MyDomainObject item : result) {
        SelectionListItem<MyDomainObject> e = new SelectionListItem<MyDomainObject>(item, false);
        selectionList.getList().add(e);
    }

    return selectionList;
}

/* Controller for POST */
@RequestMapping(value = "/xxx", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String functionPOST(
    @ModelAttribute("selectionListCommand") SelectionList<MyDomainObject> selectionListCommand,
    BindingResult result, Model model) {

    // Delete record
    someService.deleteSelectedRecords(selectionListCommand);


    return "xxx;
}

/* Service that deletes the selected records*/
public void deleteSelectedRecords(SelectionList<MyDomainObject> selectionList) {
    for (SelectionListItem<MyDomainObject> item : selectionList.getList()) {
        if (item.isSelected()) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(item.getItem());
        }
    }
}
```

At GET request, the SelectionList is populated correctly and the "T item" is of type "MyDomainObject".

At POST, the "T item" is of type "java.lang.Object" and when the "sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(item.getItem())" is executed i am getting "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.lang.Object"

Can someone please explain what is causing it and how it can be solved?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your controller method signature accepting the POST, that could be the issue - is it accepting explicitly a parameter of type SelectionList<MyDomainObject>?

Comment: Biju, yes i am explicitely accepting SelectionList<MyDomainObject>. Please take a look as i have posted the code above, "public String functionPOST(
    @ModelAttribute("selectionListCommand") SelectionList<MyDomainObject> selectionListCommand,
    BindingResult result, Model model)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned, the problem was when the @ModelAttribute("selectionListCommand") was returned at POST.

Solution is:

- Add to the controller -> **@SessionAttributes("selectionListCommand")**
- Modify class SelectionList to -> **public class SelectionList implements java.io.Serializable**

I hope that will save someone's else time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does "some magic things" and often uses reflections to get access to variables and determine the types. The types are important for Hibernate to decide which mapping to use.

In the get request you provide with `MyDomainObject.class` the correct class. This seems to be sufficient for Hibernate to find the mapping.

This is not the case for the post request. There Hibernate in the statement `delete(item.getItem())` only gets the information `getItem()` returns an object (the type `T` is removed due to the type erasure and not available for Hibernate). The information 'object' does not allow Hibernate to find the mapping for `item`.

You can try to cast the item like `delete((MyDomainObject)item.getItem())` or to put it in a well typed variable first

```
   MyDomainObject mdoItem = item.getItem();
   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(mdoItem);
```

(I'm not sure which of the two possibilities will work.)

Comment: Johanna, both ways produce the same exception, "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to MyDomainObject". As i mentioned, at POST selectionListCommand.list.item becomes of type Object. There is no information anymore in order to be casted back to the original type.

Comment: Ofcourse, if i don't use generics and i replace " T item" with "MyDomainObject item" everything works fine.

Comment: I set a breakpoint before "deleteSelectedRecords()" is executed at POST and i am seeing that the type of "T item" is erased, therefore it has to do with Spring MVC solely since Hibernate does not intefere yet.